# Having a base project on github that affects other projects based on it

Tags: git, github, windows-store-apps

Im trying to have a base project in this case a windows store app project, that would serve as base for 3 other projects ( for now ) 
what i want is having distinct features on the 3 projects, but when i change something common on base project, it changes on all 3 of them, using visual studio.

is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about Visual Studio Git integration, but I think you could manage your case with `git submodule`.

I never went the submodule way, because I think it complicate things, usually what you really need is to ensure you have the proper dependencies defined in your test/build/deploy environment, event though this may depend on the technologies you are using.